# Inserting a datetime value in database using html

Tags: html

I want to input the specific time only. I mean the date now will be automatically save when the use input the specific time. Example if user input 1:00PM then it will save in database 2017-10-28 1:00:21. the 2017-10-28 is the present day and the specific time is what user input. Sorry for my bad english.

```
<div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Time Out :</label>
            <div class="controls">
            <input type="time" id="inputEmail" name="time_out" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{5,}" placeholder="Time Out" required>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="control-group">
            <div class="controls">
            <button name="submit" type="submit" class="btn btn-success"><i class="icon-save icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
</form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-remove icon-large"></i>&nbsp;Close</button>
    </div>
</div>

<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

$timeout=$_POST['time_out'];

mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert into user_logs_tbl (time_out) values('$timeout')")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
}
?>
```

[Time Out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ansrY.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not defined time in your code.

Try replacing your php code with this.

```
 <?php
   if (isset($_POST['submit'])){

   $timeout=$_POST['time_out'];
   $timeout = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime(str_replace('-', '/', $timeout)));

   mysqli_query($dbcon,"insert into user_logs_tbl (time_out)    values('$timeout')")or die(mysqli_error($dbcon));
   }
 ?>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It works and can you solve my another problem again? I'll edit my question if you respond to me btw thank you